# How to loop through hosts and set variables at the same time with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to simplify my Ansible Playbook for the deployment of a HA-Zookeeper-Cluster (3 instances). Since I need to set the Zookeeper-ID separately for each instance it looks like this now (excerpt):

```
- hosts: zoo1
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/install-zookeeper.yml ID=1

- hosts: zoo2
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/install-zookeeper.yml ID=2

- hosts: zoo3
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/install-zookeeper.yml ID=3
```

Now I think it should somehow be possible to do this in a loop. Here's some pseudocode of what I want:

```
- for i in (1,2,3):
  hosts: "zoo{{ i }}"
  tasks:
    - include tasks/install-zookeeper.yml ID="{{ i }}"
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: What is the policy? It seems that the `ID` might be an index in the group's list, perhaps. In other words, what is the rule of assigning the `ID` to a host? Or, there might be a dictionary of `host:ID` hashes, perhaps. What is it yet?

Comment: The policy is just to have unique ID per service. It won't need to scale, so I went with the easiest way and just gaven them rigid IDs as I saw fit. The solutions in your answer would probably be better for dynamic deployments with a bit of change, so I might switch to that approach later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `ID` var per host in your inventory. This can be done directly in your inventory file or in a `host_vars/YouHostInventoryName.yml` file. See the [inventory documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) for more info on this.

For this example, we can use a basic static yaml inventory:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    zoo1:
      ID: 1
    zoo2:
      ID: 2
    zoo3:
      ID: 3
```

And now you just have to call you include on each host which will automatically get the correct `ID` from inventory:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks/install-zookeeper.yml
```

Note: [`include`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html) is still supported but will be deprecated in more or less near future. You should move to the new `<include|import>_<task|role|playbook>` as stated in the notes of the above linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of

```
- for i in (1,2,3):
  hosts: "zoo{{ i }}"
  tasks:
    - include tasks/install-zookeeper.yml ID="{{ i }}"
```

might be implemented with the inventory and the playbook below

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[cluster1]
zoo1
zoo2
zoo3
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: cluster1
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: install-zookeeper.yml
      vars:
        ID: "{{ inventory_hostname[3:0] }}"
```

---

Next option would be to use the part of the hostname that starts with a number. For example

```yaml
      vars:
        ID: "{{ inventory_hostname|
                regex_replace('^(\\D*)(.*)$', '\\2') }}"
```

---

It's possible to dynamically change the inventory. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "zoo{{ item +1 }}"
        groups: cluster1
      loop: "{{ range(0, no_of_servers|default(3)|int)|list }}"

- hosts: cluster1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname|
                 regex_replace('^(\\D*)(.*)$', '\\2') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "no_of_servers=2"

ok: [zoo1] => 
  msg: '1'
ok: [zoo2] => 
  msg: '2'
```